# How could I rewrite this non-redux into redux approach?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am kind of novice in react redux.

In my react project

I have three components

```
BigForm , FormA and FormB.
```

In BigForm, there are two state, DataA and DataB, which would be passed into FormA and FormB.

```
Question:
```

Whenever I add input value into Form A or Form B, it will also trigger unnecessary render on the other components. I heard redux may help, but I am not sure how to put this in work in this example.

```
What have thought before:
```

For some reason, it is my intention to set the state in parent, instead of having the child to held its own state, because at the end, I need to aggregate the data from all other forms for other purpose.

.Memo is not what I want too coz in my real examples, it is not working due to there is other complexity preventing it to work.
How can I avoid it? Example code would be appreciated. (please also see my edit before trying) thanks ; I heard redux may help, but I am not sure how to put this in work in this example

Below is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const FormA = (props) => {

  useEffect(()=>{ console.log('Form A was just rendered')})
  const { dataA, setDataA } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setDataA(e.target.value)}></input>
      <p>Input Form A{dataA}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const FormB = (props) => {
  const { dataB, setDataB } = props;
  useEffect(()=>{ console.log('Form B was just rendered')})
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setDataB(e.target.value)}></input>
      <p>Input Form B{dataB}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export function BigForm (props) {

  const [dataA,setDataA] = useState()
  const [dataB,setDataB] = useState()
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <FormA dataA={dataA} setDataA={setDataA}></FormA>

     <FormB dataB={dataB} setDataB={setDataB}></FormB>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would recommend do not pay attention to that re-render (this is only react virtual dom rerender and this is fast and cheap).

Comment: @AndreySmolko , thanks man ,  unfortunuly, in my real example, FormA and FormB are huge, and I also have other Form , like Form A,B,C too . That's why I am looking for redux

Comment: @MridulGupta , Thanks,  The big form actually has a button on it to aggregate all the data. Let say it will make a api call that's based on the data from Form A,B,C,D,E,F